# Is there a way to automate the process of django templates translation?

Tags: django, automation, django-templates

I would like to translate all my Django templates, Which means I need to go through every word or sentence in my templates and add the code _() to it.
For ex
This: `<h1>hello</h1>`
Will be this: `<h1>_("hello")</h1>`

But I would like to do it automatically since I have many many sentences, It doesn't matter if it's software or an online tool or a text editor that can automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use blocktranslate tag
see the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktranslate-template-tag

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for since the blocktranslate doesn't accept html written inside of it.
The best way is to have an automation script that goes through every html tag and checks the text inside of it and add the _() to it